# What is the meaning of this rather complex sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> What were her many mysteries, she tantalized herself, replaying all the loves she'd ever known.

The above is from [the Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tantalize).

Can you paraphrase the sentence, expressing clearly what it says?

Comment: The structure and meaning are not clear to me (native English speaker). I _think_, that "What were her many mysteries" is a quoted question, and _tantalized_ is being used in an  unusual way to mean "tantalized herself by saying to her self".

Comment: I agree with @ColinFine.  It's not a very good example.  If it were shown in context the sentence might make more sense.

Comment: I can't find a source of that quote, only plagiarism.

Comment: @WeatherVane What does that has to do with plagiarism?

Comment: @Juya I was looking for the source of the example shown by Longman, but all I found was sites which have copied that quote (some mention Longman) but no text of the context which originally used it. Copying someone else's material without acknowledgement is plagiarism.